# Is there a good way of adapting Megacity One maps from actual maps of New York?

Tags: map-making, online-resources, post-apocalyptic

My group is starting a Traveller Judge Dredd RPG adventure set in Megacity One (New York area). We'd like to make, or appropriate, a street-level map of a specific few Sectors of the city, to serve as our campaign's home base, and populate with FILTHY CRIME.

Does anybody here know of somewhere I might find:

- Actual Judge Dredd Megacity One maps.
- Other post-apocalyptic megacity maps which might serve as a basis.

or

- Some relatively clean maps of New York that are adaptable (or vectorised) enough for me to add a layer of design, recolour & cover in doodads and craters?
- and presumably an image pack of some kind of map elements like craters & megablocks.

Comment: Interested in this, as I'm doing something similar for Chicago...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://twintailedcomet.com has a Google Map view with all labels removed.

It starts zoomed in on a city in Europe, but if you know where New York is, you can zoom in there instead, and print or screenshot it.

Comment: Oh, wow, this is fantastic! Thank you so much for this link. =)

Comment: [Theik](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/109510/theik) posted it in chat. I think it might be his site?

Comment: I've been trying to some documentation on it or something, so I can figure out how to link it to a particular place... would be great to use as a zooming map we can use to flag CRIME during adventures, and create zoomed-in maps of districts.

Comment: Tried appending stuff like "@40.6908185,-73.9865475" to the URL, but isn't working for me. @Theik, thank you very much for creating this. Is there some kind of functionality for pointing it at a specific place?

Comment: Wow, did not expect to randomly find my own site linked here! It is very much a work in progress / trial thingy, the idea being that eventually people can select their own colors and add new map pointers for a fully usable RPG map, however it's not quite that far yet. Glad to see it can still help you in its current state.

Comment: Thanks - I'll keep an eye on it for later features, and for now will get to work adapting it to a nice Judge Dredd style map for my campaign. Cheers! =)